# Marquee span/content of span

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have placed some spans, containing images an text, into another span wich can be scrolled to the side. I would like to scroll these spans from side to side, just like the Marquee effect for text. Most examples I have found just support marquee for text and not for spans. Has anyone got some hints/code to help me out?

thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeking a thing called "carousel". There are plenty of examples on the network... You could of course write it on your own.

Jquery plugins directory:
http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/carousel/